# Variable global no se actualiza correctamente dentro de la función - JS

Tags: javascript, array, objeto

Tengo la siguiente función en JS. Quiero que la función devuelva un arreglo con objetos donde el valor de sus propiedades vayan de 0 a 4, pero en lugar de obtener ese resultado, todos los valores de las propiedades me dan 5, en lugar de ir de 0 a 4.

```html
function arregloDeObjetos(numero){
    
    let arreglo = []
    let objeto = {}
    let n = 1

    for(let i = 0; i < numero; i++){
        objeto["valor"] = n
        arreglo.push(objeto)
        n++
    }
    console.log(arreglo)
}
```

¿alguien podría ayudarme explicándome cuál puede ser el motivo? muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema que tienes es debido al manejo de la variable 'objeto', por cada push esta variable se referencia y cada vez que se actualiza todas las referencias cambian, [aquí](https://medium.com/@naveenkarippai/learning-how-references-work-in-javascript-a066a4e15600) un artículo que explica más a detalle como funcionan las referencias en JavaScript. Si no mal entiendo debería ser así:

```
function arregloDeObjetos(numero){

let arreglo = []
let n = 1

    for(let i = 0; i < numero; i++){
        let objeto = {}
        objeto["valor"] = n+'';
        arreglo.push(objeto)
        n++
    }
    console.log(arreglo)
}
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias, todo muy claro y me sirve también la documentación compartida. Un saludo!!